# Vue & Vite disable code splitting / chunking

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, code-splitting

I have built a small application in Vue/TypeScript and with Vite and i am trying to build the files using `vite build` but this is chunking the files. The file is to be placed on other peoples website with just a `div` tag and a `script` tag. The only issue with this is that Vite is splitting the JS files into chunks.

this is my basic config file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js"

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({ defineModel: true }),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin()
  ],
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {},
      },
    }
  },
})
```

I have also tried setting `manualChunks` to `undefined` but had no luck with this either. I've read some articles and other posts saying that this is the correct way but I am struggling and any help would be much appreciated.

build script is `vite build`

**setup includes:**

- vite: `"^5.0.11"`
- vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js: `"^3.4.0"`
- vue: `^3.3.11"`

Comment: Could you please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example]? Codes are not split into chunks in the template created by `pnpm create vite my-vue-app --template vue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rollup option

https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-inlinedynamicimports

```
output:{
  inlineDynamicImports: true
}
```

> This will inline dynamic imports instead of creating new chunks to create a single bundle. Only possible if a single input is provided. Note that this will change the execution order: A module that is only imported dynamically will be executed immediately if the dynamic import is inlined.

Comment: I tried the other options but this is the option that seemed to work. I had to camel case the key tho to `inlineDynamicImports: true` for it to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bryan88 copied from the url, lost the camel case, sorry, a sloppy copy-paste

Comment: haha, not a problem! Again, thank you for your help! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I used this vite-configuration to get a single js (and css file) once:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The `output:` part is the important one.

Comment: I suggest keeping the hashes in the file names. They are useful for asset caching.

Comment: @ouuan In general you are right of course - but the poster said that the script is going to be loaded from other websites. In that case the name has to stay the same all the time otherwise you have to change it on the other websites all the time.